# localhost: socket: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, centos

When I attempt to use a socket (not TCP) connection to connect to MySQL 5.7.21 using PHP 7.2.4 `mysqli_connect()` on Centos 7.4 I get an error:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory

## php.ini

> mysqli.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock

## my.cnf

> [mysqld]
>    socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
>    ...
>    [client]
>    socket=/tmp/mysql.sock

MySQL connection from command line works fine:

```
/usr/local/mysql57/bin/mysql --socket tmp/mysql.sock --host localhost -u root -p
```

> Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
>   Your MySQL connection id is 3
>   Server version: 5.7.21 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

```
ls -l /tmp/my*
```

> srwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 0 Apr 19 22:01 /tmp/mysql.sock
>   -rw------- 1 mysql mysql 5 Apr 19 22:01 /tmp/mysql.sock.lock

```
ps -edf | grep mysql
```

> mysql     3593  3329  0 22:01 ?        00:00:03 /usr/local/mysql57/bin/mysqld --defaults-file=/usr/local/mysql57/my.cnf --basedir=/usr/local/mysql57 --datadir=/mysql57 --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql57/lib/plugin --log-error=myhost.err --pid-file=myhost.pid --socket=/tmp/mysql.sock --port=3306

```
$dblink = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'rootpass', 'testdb', 3306, '/tmp/mysql.sock');
if (mysqli_connect_errno($dblink)) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

MySQL generic tar.gz was installed. I'm using nginx 1.12.2. If I use 127.0.0.1 or locahost:3306 such that TCP is used it works fine. Why doesn't socket work?

## Update #1

I have another Centos 7.4 image with MySQL 5.7.11 which works with socket. However, I don't start it using `systemctl`. I also noticed that even though it's running there is no /tmp/mysql.sock.lock file, just /tmp/mysql.sock
Other than that it's mostly the same, in fact, /tmp/mysql.sock isn't specified anywhere in php.ini nor my.cnf files.

Comment: does PDO work??

Comment: Same error using pdo.

Answer (score 3):

In my case solution was to change localhost to 127.0.0.1

I was connecting from WSL to Windows Instance of MySQL Server

Answer (score 0):

This could be a simple permissions problem. Seems like only root/current user/sudo has rights to the tmp folder (which is why terminal works and php doesn't). 
Also, as a reference to my own Centos 7 mysql setup:
 my datadir and socket locations are identical hence why mysql has access to the .sock file

```
--datadir=/var/lib/mysql --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: ls -l /  shows 777 for /tmp so anyone can access it: drwxrwxrwt. 11 root  root   4096 Apr 20 02:29 tmp

Answer (score 0):

You want to connect to mysql via socket in your code

```
$dblink = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'rootpass', 'testdb', 3306, '/tmp/mysql.sock');
```

try to replace this with:

```
$dblink = mysqli_connect('/tmp/mysql.sock', 'root', 'rootpass', 'testdb', 3306);
```

there is a solution available here as well https://serverfault.com/questions/673854/how-to-let-php-connect-to-database-by-using-unix-socket-joomla hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't work either, error is: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known. That was for mysql_connect not mysqli so I think it's outdated.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used `strace /usr/bin/php test.php` and found more info:

> connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX,
>   sun_path="/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"}, 29) = -1 ENOENT (No such file
>   or directory)

This was due to me running inside a jail with no access to the local socket file so I was forced to use TCP protocol by changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 in the php code.